# Sending email from R in AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, sendmail, sendmailr

I am trying to send myself a test email from an AWS Virtual Machine (using an EC2 instance.)

My R code runs great, but I am now trying to send a test email to my email address using sendmailR.

I get the following error message:

Error in socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) :
  localhost:25 cannot be opened

```
 install.packages("sendmailR")
 library(sendmailR)

 sendmail(from = "XXXX@gmail.com",
      to = "YYYY@gmail.com",
      subject = "Subject of the email",
      body = "Body of the email",
      smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 80 , user.name = "XXXX@gmail.com", passwd = "XXXX", ssl = TRUE),
      authenticate = TRUE,
      send = TRUE)
```

Does anyone know how this is overcome?

Comment: Is this code being executed on an AWS EC2 Instance?

Comment: It is, exactly correct!

Comment: Have you tried opening port 25 in the security group of the EC2 instance?

Comment: I'm new to AWS but have an opened port (25) both inbound and outbound:                           HTTP - Port 80, SSH - Port 22, SMTP - Port 25

Comment: You could also try using the `aws.ses` package to send email via HTTP, especially if you're just trying to reach out to yourself. Another option would be `aws.sns`. Both on CRAN.